# Customize openstreetmap tilelayer render with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I'm currently struggling with an issue. 
I'm developing an app with reactJS and I wanted to display a map with a marker that the user could move and so on. Therefore, I used leaflet with the react-leaflet package and I used openstreetmap as TileLayer. Until here, everything is OK. 
The thing is that I would like to be able to customize the render of the OpenStreetMap (like put the roads in red, forrest in another green, not display sea border and so on...) so that it would suit more with the design of my website. 
I tried to find some solution on the web, but nothing convinced me a lot or maybe I didn't understand them well. I think there is a way to do that with Leaflet VectorGrid https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html 
but it is not very clear for me.

I specify that I want to use OpenStreetMap and not solutions such as mapbox. 
 
 I think it is kind of useless but here is my code to display my map to show you how I did it :

```
      <Map center={position} zoom={12}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        <Marker
          position={position ? position : TOULOUSE_GPS_LOCATION}
          draggable={true}
          onDragend={handleMarkerPositionChange}
        >
          <Popup>
            Vous pouvez déplacer le marqueur afin <br /> d'ajuster au mieux votre position
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
    </Wrapper>
```

Thanks in advance for you responses !

Comment: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/

Comment: @IvanSanchez don't you know if there is another way to do that without having to use my own tile server and doing it on the client side.
Because it would be a lot of constraints just to be able to customize a bit my map

Comment: If you «don't want solutions like mapbox», no. You'll need to get your vector tiles or your customized tiles from somewhere, so I'm explicitly ignoring any vector/raster tile providers in the list at https://switch2osm.org/providers/